# Insanity Checking a JS Word Suggestion Implantation

Tags: javascript, search

## Origin

This is a spell checker type function for our product search function.

I tried [Fuse.js](http://fusejs.io/) and it was to slow.
I tried [FuzzySort.js](https://github.com/farzher/fuzzysort) and it was fast enough not accurate enough.

## Problem

Take in a user text and get relevant suggestions of what the user is typing out of a set of possible words. These suggestions should produce a score to help show relevance. As the final word list is about 50,000 unique words we only want the highest 5 scores as suggestions.

Speed needs to happen on a single core and under 100 ms with 50,000 words.

We only have 100Mb of Ram available

### Example of Problem

#### Word List: *'apple', 'banana', 'apricot'*

#### Input: 'epp'

The weights are arbtrary in this example.

#### Output: 'apple' score: .8, 'apricot' score: .3, 'banana' score: 0

## Approach

We can make a graph of all the characters of each word by position that points to the words itself. By doing this we can take the input and go through this graph and pull all words that match that position of each character in the input then add up the matches to get a score.

### Example

#### Word List: *'apple', 'banana', 'apricot'*

#### Graph

```
{ a: {
       0: ['apple', 'apricot'], 
       1: ['banana'],
       3: ['banana'],
       5: ['banana']
     },
  b: {
       0: ['banana']
     },
  c: {
       4: ['apricot']
     }
  ....
}
```

As the character, 'a' is in 'apple' and 'apricot' in index 0 Graph['a'][0] would return ['apple', 'apricot']

So the user types in 'epp' there is no word with 'e' in index 0 so [] returns, however 'p' in index 1 returns ['apple', 'apricot'] and 'p' index 2 returns ['apple']

So the returned values are [], ['apple', 'apricot'], ['apple'] we can concat these together and count the occurrence of each word producing a score.

#### Implimentation

As I was testing this out I got 30ms timeframes and added a threshold to drop words that didn't meet a standard of relavence based on length of the input.

```js
class SpellChecker {
    constructor () {
        this.options = {
        limit : 5, // How many words can be returned,
        threshold: 0.7 // 1 complete match, 0 complete mismatch
        },
        this.characterGraph = {}
    }
    search (text) {
        const characters = text.split('')
        let words = []

        // Get words from graph
        _.forEach(characters, (character, index) => {
            words = words.concat(this.characterGraph[character][index] || [])
        })

        // Group words and get score
        let group = {}
        _.forEach(words, (word) => {
            if (!group[word]) group[word] = 0
            group[word]++
        })

        // Get the highest score words
        const highestScore = []
        for (let index = 0; index < this.options.limit; index++) {
            highestScore.push({ score: -Infinity })
        }
        let lowest = _.minBy(highestScore, 'score').score

        for(let word in group) {
            const count = group[word]
            if (count > lowest) {
                highestScore[_.findIndex(highestScore, ['score', lowest])] = {
                    score: count,
                    target: word
                }
                lowest = _.minBy(highestScore, 'score').score
            }
        }

        // Filter if score is less the relevant and return
        return _.filter(highestScore, (word) => word.score >= Math.round(text.length * this.options.threshold))
    }
    init (words) {
        _.forEach(words, (word) => {
            const characters = word.split('')
            _.forEach(characters, (character, index) => {
                this.characterGraph[character] = this.characterGraph[character] || {}
                this.characterGraph[character][index] = this.characterGraph[character][index] || []
                this.characterGraph[character][index].push(word)
            })
        })
    }
}

const spellChecker = new SpellChecker()

// Create Graph
spellChecker.init(['apple', 'banana', 'apricot'])

// Search
const result = spellChecker.search('epp')

// Print
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

### Question

This method solves the speed issue but at the cost of accuracy of a match.

#### Example of accuracy issue

#### Word List: *'apple', 'banana', 'apricot'*

#### Input: 'eapricot'

In Theory 'apricot' should be the best match but in this case it would receive a score of 0.

The best I can think of is looping of the processing a range of the word.

#### Example of Range

Input: 'eapricot'
Range: 1

process: ['apricot', 'eapricot', ' eapricot'] as it removes and add 1 character to the word it can see if the user is off by position but this is a poor solution in my mind.

### Any Thoughts?

Comment: You might find you get better responses for something like this on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good point @HarryCutts